# Magit custom commands

Tags: magit

Magit displays the progression of multi-step commands with popup windows. For example, pressing <kbd>c</kbd> brings up the commit menu, whence pressing <kbd>a</kbd> will invoke `magit-commit-amend`.

I would like to include my own command `magit-commit-snapshot`, and invoke it with <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>. 
 `n: Snapshot` should be displayed in the commit menu, after `s: Squash`.

How can I do this? I can see that the bindings exist in `magit-key-mode.el`, but I don't see an easy way to add to them from my `.emacs`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting with `v2.1.0` you can do so using this:

```
(magit-define-popup-action 'magit-commit-popup
  ?n "Snapshot" 'magit-commit-snapshot)
```

---

The next release of Magit will replace magit-popup with [transient](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/).  (As of writing the current Magit release is v2.90.1.)  Using transient, you can add a custom command with `transient-append-suffix`:

```
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-commit "c"
  '("n" "Snapshot" magit-commit-snapshot))
```

For more information, see the [section on modifying existing transients](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Modifying-Existing-Transients.html#Modifying-Existing-Transients) in the manual.

Comment: @tarsius, I appreciate how you keep your answer up to date as Magit changes.

Comment: @tarsius I think this no longer works with `transient.el`? Is there a more up-to-date answer?

Comment: For anyone wondering how to figure out what prefix command goes with a key (e.g. `'magit-commit` in this case): enter the magit transient (`C-x M-g`), then hit `C-x l`, then type the leader key: it will show the prefix command in the minibuffer. E.g. to find the prefix command for `"l"` (log): `C-x M-g C-x l l`, and you will see: `magit-log`.